# On div hover, display a new div on a third one

Tags: javascript, css

Say I have 2 divs, positioned side by side (with some intermediate elements between them): A (left) and B(right). When hovering over B, I wish to have another div(C) appear over the left one (A).

I know how to toggle the display none/block properties but I don't know how to write the condition so the div C can appear on another div, not the one that we're hovering over.

Can this be done?

```
<div className="A">
   <h2>About me</h2>
</div>

<div className="B">
   <div>
       <Link className="link1-to-project" to="/project1">
       <h2>Project 1</h2>
   <div className="C"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[codeply demo here](https://www.codeply.com/p/MSs1JL4Y1b)

Html

```
<div id="a">
 Div A
<div id="c">Div C</div>
</div>
<div id="b">Div B</b>
```

css

```
#a, #b{
float:left;
height:100px;
width:100px;
color:#fff;
background-color:#ffcc66;
margin:10px;
text-align:center;
}
#c{
background-color:#000;
margin:10px;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
function mouseOver() {
document.getElementById("c").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOut() {
document.getElementById("c").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/mq5bza81/1/

---

https://jsfiddle.net/mq5bza81/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
   
    <style>
      .wrapper {
        position: relative;
      }

      .b:hover+.c {
        display: block;
      }

      .c {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="a">AAA</div>
      <div class="b">BBB</div>
      <div class="c">CCC</div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```